# Executing a stored procedure with Dapper doesn't return column headers if no rows are present

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am executing a stored procedure with Dapper which returns dynamic pivot query, columns. I have noticed if there are no results Dapper does not even return the column headers. I print my results to excel and if there are no rows, thats fine, but I would still like to print out the column header.

So for instance if this being returned from the Sproc, just column headers

**TSBNumber System1 System2 System3**

The following obs, count is 0 but I still need to get the column headers. Is this possible or I would manually need to add column headers it to my datatable when there are no results?   Or Should I add empty row in my SQL so dapper will get a count of 1 and print out?

```
   var obs = cnn.Query(sql: "spExportServiceTSB", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);


  var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("@StartDate", StartDate);
            p.Add("@EndDate", EndDate);
            p.Add("@SelectedSystemIDs", SelectedSystemIDs);
            p.Add("@SelectedTsbIDs", SelectedTsbIDs);
            p.Add("@UserRoleID", UserRoleID);
            var obs = cnn.Query(sql: "spExportServiceTSB", param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            var dt = ToDataTable(obs);

            return ExportDatatableToHtml(dt);
```

**Sproc**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spExportServiceTSB]                            
(@StartDate datetime,                            
@EndDate datetime,                                   
@SelectedSystemIDs nvarchar (2000) = NULL,    
@SelectedTsbIDs nvarchar (2000) = NULL,   
@UserRoleID int
)                            
AS                            

DECLARE @PlatformID INT = NULL

IF(@SelectedSystemIDs = '')
BEGIN
SET @SelectedSystemIDs = NULL
END

IF(@SelectedTsbIDs = '')
BEGIN
SET @SelectedTsbIDs = '0'
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 1)    
 BEGIN     
  SET @PlatformID = 1     
  END  

IF(@UserRoleID = 2)  
BEGIN  
SET @PlatformID = 2  
END  

IF (@UserRoleID = 3)    
BEGIN    
SET @PlatformID = 12    
END   

IF(@UserRoleID = 4)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 3
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 5)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 4
END

IF(@UserRoleID = 6)
BEGIN 
SET @PlatformID = 0
END

DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =  
   COALESCE(
     @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' +  cast(SystemFullName as Nvarchar) + ']',
     '[' + cast(SystemFullName as varchar)+ ']'
   )
FROM System 
WHERE (@SelectedSystemIDs IS NULL OR  System.ID IN(select  * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedSystemIDs, ',')))     
AND ((@PlatformID =0) OR  (System.PlatformID = @PlatformID) OR (@PlatformID = 12 AND System.PlatformID <= 2))  

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
   SELECT *
   FROM (
     SELECT
       TSBNumber [TSBNumber],
       SystemFullName,
       ClosedDate
     FROM ServiceEntry 
     INNER JOIN System 
       ON ServiceEntry.SystemID = System.ID
     where
      (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber IS NOT NULL)
       AND 
       (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate IS NOT NULL)
       AND
       ( 
       (''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') OR
         (ServiceEntry.TSBNumber in (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(''' + @SelectedTsbIDs + ''', ''' + ',' + ''')))
        )  
        AND (
         (''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = '''+ '0' + ''') 
        OR(System.PlatformID = ''' + cast(@PlatformID as varchar(10)) + ''')
        --OR(''' + CAST(@PlatformID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ''' = ''' + '12' + ''' AND System.PlatformID <=  ''' + '2' + ''')
        )
        AND
        (ServiceEntry.ClosedDate between ''' + convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 120)  + '''  and   ''' +  convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 120) + ''')

   ) AS PivotData
   PIVOT (
     MAX(ClosedDate)
     FOR SystemFullName IN (
       ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
     ) 
   ) AS PivotTable
' 



EXECUTE (@PivotTableSQL)
--print (@PivotTableSQL)
```

Comment: Minor aside: you may want to look at sp_executesql if you are building tsql inside tsql - it allows you to parameterize (injection safety and cache plan reuse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, Query doesn't, because it has no rows upon which to attach metadata. There is an ExecuteReader method, but at that point you aren't gaining much over ADO.NET, unless I add a method to turn an IDataReader into a series of `dynamic` rows or materilize into some type. I could add those things - it just takes work.

Comment: I see, Thanks for confirming. I normally use Entity framework for executing stored procedure populating a model with static columns but in this case I think I may just add a null row by doing a UNION ALL select NULL, ''where NOT EXISTS (here I will put the same query).